# Custom validation function with AJV

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

We are using AJV to validate data.

Here's the schema

```
const mySchema = {
  $schema: "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  $id: "some_schema_id",
  title: "My list",
  type: "array",
  items: {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      my_list_key: {
        type: "string",
        maxLength: 20,
        title: "My List",
        readOnly: false,
        isRequired: true,
        disabled: true,
      },
      my_list_itm: {
        type: "array",
        items: {
          type: "object",
          uniqueItems: true,
          properties: {
            date_fr: {
              type: "string",
              format: "date",
              title: "Date From",
              description: "Date From",
              tooltip: "Individual Date or the Start of a Range of Dates",
              readOnly: false,
              disabled: false,
            },
            date_to: {
              type: "string",
              format: "date",
              title: "Date To",
              description: "Date To",
              tooltip: "Optional End of a Range of Dates",
              readOnly: false,
              disabled: false,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Our requirement is to check for each record that `date_fr` is always less that `date_to`. I don't want to add any extra keyword.

TLDR: How to add custom validation function to ajv schema.

Comment: Don't add to your schema, just write it as a separate function.

Comment: doesn't seem to be good. Validation is the only thing why we have defined schema.

Comment: Yeah but you're going to fight an uphill battle modifying JSON Schema vocabularies and AJV to validate everything about your own business logic. It's normal that your schema validates your structure but not everything about your business logic.

Comment: Okay seems viable now. But is that the only option we have?